# Read messages programmatically from Google group

Tags: google-groups, google-groups-api

I'll like to run some analysis on messages that are stored in Google group which is part of Google apps domain (busines).

Is it possible to read them via API?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, there is no API that allows reading of Google Group messages. If you have a Gmail user that has been a member of the group and received those messages, you could try using Gmail API against that user.

Comment: is this API available yet?

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest way, but it is possible to use the Vault API to make a matter, export the file, and get the results. Depending on your use case, this may work, but requires very elevated permissions.